# How to implement the time.Sleep after the template execution?

Tags: go, time, sleep

In this function, I want the time to sleep after the execution of the main template. and print the message after 1 minute is passed but it gives me two problems.

1. It takes 1 minute to load a template instead of sleeping after the template execution.
2. It gives the message to add the `return`. When I write `return nil`, it gives me another error on this code `time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) fmt.Println("Time Passed")` that `unreachable code`.

I used the middleware for this `Main()` function to not repeat `log.Fatal(err)` for each error message.

**Code**

```
func Main(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    match := Get("id1")
    if match {
        return MainTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
        fmt.Println("Time Passed")
    } else {
        return LoginTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code after a `return` statement is unreachable, because the function will return before executing those statements. If you want to print something 1 minute after the response is written, you can do:

```
func Main(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    match := Get("id1")
    if match {
        go func() {
           time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
           fmt.Println("Time Passed")
        }()
        return MainTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        return LoginTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    }
    return nil
}
```

This will start a goroutine that will sleep for a minute and print.